# Perform polling request for async task

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, system.reactive, rx-swift

I have already written an Rx query to perform an async task in a timer. This also handles scenario where i need to discard order request whose response comes later. This is written in C#:

```
public static IObservable<T> PollingAync<T> (Func<Task<T>> AsyncCall, double TimerDuration)
        {
            return Observable
         .Create<T>(o =>
         {
             var z = 0L;
             return
                 Observable
                     .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerDuration))
                     .SelectMany(nr =>
                         Observable.FromAsync<T>(AsyncCall),
                         (nr, obj) => new { nr, obj})
                     .Do(res => z = Math.Max(z, res.nr))
                     .Where(res => res.nr >= z)
                     .Select(res => res.obj)
                     .Subscribe(o);
         });

    }
```

I wish to write the same implementation in swift which handles an async task and also discard order request whose response comes later. I wish to write this in swift3.0

Since i am new to swift please help to let me know how can i achieve the same result in swift **without using Rx**.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Rx?

Comment: @DanielT. Actually for the team, Rx is a completely new concept and this will take some learning time to do so. Hence I am trying not to introduce anything which might hinder the team in future.

Comment: Okay, it's pretty painful to write this without Rx though... It might be easier to teach the team how to use Rx.

Comment: @DanielT. Sure i got your point. Just a quick question. Can you help me to understand how do we handle Async operations which generally have callbacks in some form like blocks using Rx. Actually in C# its pretty easy to handle async operation as those done using Task.

Comment: The basic signature of an async call would be `func asyncCall<T>(result: (Result<T>) -> Void)` where result is defined as: `enum Result<T> { case success(T), failure(Error) }` but such a call isn't cancelable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an interesting question to answer...

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

typealias Cancel = () -> Void

func pollingAsync<T>(asyncCall: @escaping (@escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) -> Cancel, duration: TimeInterval, callback: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) -> Cancel {
    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .milliseconds(Int(duration * 1000)), leeway: .milliseconds(10))

    var asyncCallCancel: Cancel? = nil
    timer.setEventHandler {
        asyncCallCancel?()
        asyncCallCancel = asyncCall {
            callback($0)
        }
    }
    timer.resume()
    return {
        asyncCallCancel?()
        timer.cancel()
    }
}
```

To use the above, you would do something like this:

```
let cancel = pollingAsync(asyncCall: myAsyncOp, duration: 2.0) {
    print($0)
}
```

If you lose track of the `Cancel` object that is returned from this function, you won't be able to shut down the timer.

For reference, here is the equivalent code in RxSwift:

```
func pollingAsync<T>(asyncCall: @escaping () -> Observable<T>, duration: TimeInterval) -> Observable<Event<T>> {
    return Observable<Int>.interval(duration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .flatMapLatest { _ in
            asyncCall().materialize().filter { !$0.isCompleted }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was actually trying to achieve the same.